# rails devise routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails and this is my first app. Currently using rails 3.2.11 and devise 2.2.3 for authentication.

The problem is after signing in, the application returns 404 and says that it was not able to find a route for 'users' controller and 'show' action.

I have a home controller for static pages and a user controller for the user. I have generated the User model using the rails generate command. My config/routes.rb is as below.

```
devise_for :users
resources  :users
root :to => 'home#index'
```

---

> > Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-29 15:44:25 +0530
> >     Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
> >       Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cHXjNbgzEx2YsHX/AMb1oxjStY75IVHc9wT40NUOdJM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"r@e.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
> >       User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'r@e.com' LIMIT 1
> >        (0.1ms)  begin transaction
> >        (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2013-01-29 10:06:46.145781', "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-01-29 10:14:26.063767', "sign_in_count" = 66, "updated_at" = '2013-01-29 10:14:26.067024' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
> >        (188.0ms)  commit transaction
> >     Completed 404 Not Found in 365ms

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
```

And I have modified the applications controller as below

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_url(resource)
end
```

What I am trying to do is that once the user logs in, I want to show the user specific information. For that I modified the after_sign_in_path_for(). Any hints on how I can get the desired results?

My rake routes output is below

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                    root        /                              home#index
```

Comment: If I remove the after_sign_in_path_for(), I get a 302

Redirected by /home/sthustfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@myapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:135:in `redirect_to'\  Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 352ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need on your `application_controller.rb`

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   user_url(current_user)
  end
```

Take a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to%3A-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out

Just try it on a clean installation of rails/devise and working properly. I think you should have some redirection in `users_controller.rb` and therefore does not work properly!. Please remove any filter or redirect you have in your controllers and test that code

Give a shot!

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However with this change, I see a recursive GET request for /users/sign_in. Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-29 17:28:54 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (35.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected by ruby-1.9.3-p327@myapp/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:131:in `require_no_authentication'
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 39ms

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I also had to make the following change in routes.rb to fix some of the other issues - resources  :users, only: [:show, :index]